Need guidance using 4 Pico PiRP2040 and getting variation in output signals
I am using a PICO RP2040 where the trigger signal (reference voltage) is connected to GP14. I’ve programmed the Picomite to set a trigger value for a falling edge, which means the trigger should activate when the signal reaches 0.8 V. However, I’m encountering an issue where the output voltages I’m getting are higher than expected—they should be lower or close to 0.8 V. The trigger signal frequency is set at 360 Hz, and the input voltage is a 1.2 V AC sine wave at the same frequency. Currently, the output voltages from all ADC channels are between 0.85 and 0.87 V. When I increase the frequency to 400 Hz, 450 Hz, or 500 Hz, the output voltages rise even higher, which is confusing. Could you please help me identify where I might be making a mistake?
Kind regards
Hasham

Try writing in paragraphs.
